# Vaadin - set window size to wrap its contents

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I have a custom window that extends **com.vaadin.ui.Window**, inside the window I put **com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet** and into the TabSheet couple of custom components that extend **com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout**.

Everything is correctly placed inside, but the window appears totally minimized. How to extend it to show all contents properly, but without using **.setSizeFull()** as I dont want to stretch it to whole screen?

I tried **.setSizeFull()** to TabSheet and its contents, but that didn't helped at all.

Setting custom height and width for the Window works, but this is not what I intend to do...

Comment: Provide some code and a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: A window nust have a size, it does not resize on cintent sizes

Comment: Did you try with undefined size for components and window?

Comment: Indeed, `tabSheet.setSizeUndefined()` worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments area, a **Window** must have a size.
I myself would have preferred that the window adapts itself to the screen size or browser size but that is how it works.